# how to start a new line after inserting a figure without indentation at the beginning of this new line?

Tags: indentation

```
\section{last paragraph}
Here are some words in the last paragraph. Now a figure is inserted below.
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{...jpg}
\caption[Example .]{.,,}
\label{...}
\end{figure}
Now I want to start a new line after this figure. But there is always indentation at the begining. How to delete this indentation?
```

Here is the complied result:
[image]

I add the usage exmaple:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\section{Paragraph}
Here are some words in the last paragraph. Now a figure is inserted below.
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{A picture of a gull.}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Penguins.jpg}
\end{figure}
Now I want to start a new line after this figure. But there is always indentation at the begining. How to delete this indentation?
\end{document}
```

Here is the compiled result:

[image]

Comment: an indentation should only occur at start of a paragraph, so if you have a blank line before or after the figure. If it is occurring when you  have no blank line that looks like a bug, please post a usable example that reproduces the problem, not a fragment

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  hallo David , i have added a usable example.

Comment: @Werner this is not a duplicate as if you need `\noindent` here it's a float package bug/

Comment: Dont use `[H]` figure option! With `[htb]` or `[!h]` you will obtain nicer and desired results.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Floats have no concern over paragraphs, with or without the [H] option. If this was changed in the float package you may have just as many people requesting an option to have it reversed.

Comment: @Werner I don't understand your comment, it's clearly a bug in `H` it should work the same way as a normal float option and respect paragraph starts.

Comment: Well formulated question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to include `\noindent` at the beginning of the first line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,demo]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\section{Paragraph}
Here are some words in the last paragraph. Now a figure is inserted below.
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{A picture of a gull.}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Penguins.jpg}
\end{figure}
\noindent Now I want to start a new line after this figure. But there is always indentation at the begining. How to delete this indentation?
\end{document}
```

That leeds to:

[image]

Comment: No. If you need no indent that is a bug.

Comment: You are right, but in that case it would solve the problem.

Comment: using \noindent sometimes appears bug, but i have no better method to solve this. This time i use it without bug.

Answer (score 9):

This looks like a bug in the float package, here is the start of a fix, I show the image included with and without a blank line after the figure

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand\float@endH{\@endfloatbox\vskip\intextsep
  \if@flstyle\setbox\@currbox\float@makebox\columnwidth\fi
  \box\@currbox\vskip\intextsep\relax\@doendpe}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Paragraph}

xx

Here are some words in the last paragraph. Now a figure is inserted below.
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{A picture of a gull.}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}
Now I want to start a new line after this figure. But there is always indentation at the begining. How to delete this indentation?

Here are some words in the last paragraph. Now a figure is inserted below.
\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{A picture of a gull.}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{figure}

Now I want to start a new line after this figure. But there is always indentation at the begining. How to delete this indentation?






\end{document}
```

Comment: probably the bug inherited from the original `here` package that defined `H`.  I wonder who wrote that?

Comment: well, the whole `[H]` thingy is a bug, so...

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to include `\noindent` manually every time.

It's enough to define what happens after every `figure` environment:

```
\AfterEndEnvironment{figure}{\noindent\ignorespaces}
```

Remember to **remove any blank lines between `\end{figure}` and the start of your paragraph.**

[image]

Tip: you can also do the same after other kinds of environments, for example after definitions:

```
\AfterEndEnvironment{definition}{\noindent\ignorespaces}
```

Comment: This will do the wrong thing in the common case that there is a blank line after the figure. LaTeX almost never uses `\noindent` to suppress paragraph indentation for this reason.

Comment: Well, removing blank lines is a precondition of my answer, so technically it will never do the wrong thing if OP follows it entirely.