# remove space for text after figures or tables

Tags: miktex

The code is as follows

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{figure}
\caption{Comparison elements in a row of $A_1$ and $B_1$}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}
The above Figure shows that ...
```

The above is what I usually do in Latex. But I found the text after an inserted figures always has a space at the front. Like in this case there is a white space before

```
The above Figure shows that ...
```

How to remove the white space? One solution I know is to insert "\\" ,after$\end{figure}$.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27804/36296 help? Or `\noindent The above Figure ....`? Please do not use \\ (with the exception of tables)

Comment: `\noindent The above Figure show that …` should do the trick.

Comment: Even [h] should begin and end with \vskip\intextsep,

Comment: It will not resolve the issue by using `\noindent`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310777/how-to-start-a-new-line-after-inserting-a-figure-without-indentation-at-the-begi seems to be an identical question to mine. Some mentioned that this is bug in float package.